# General topology problem

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Let $T$ be a topology on $X$ such that all infinite subsets of $X$ belong to $T$. Prove that $T$ is the discrete topology on $X$.
i know that all the infinite subsets of X are already in T,so what i has to do is to prove all finite set all belong too T.so if show that any  singleton set  belong to T,then its done.but main problem comes how i show intersection of two infinite set is singleton set???

Comment: Is this an exercise?

Comment: yes.i have this problem

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Consider two open sets which intersect in only one point.

Comment: i m not able to find two infinite set which intersect in one point

Comment: Use that there is a subset of X which is bijective to $\mathbb N$

Comment: how does it have a subset which is one t one correspond to N??

Comment: The cut of two open sets is open and if all the sets $\{n\}$ are open then the topology is discrete by definition.

Comment: @Eklavya Here is an example $(2\mathbb N\cup 1) \cap (2\mathbb N+1)=\{1\}$. So the cut of the two infinite sets is just 1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in X$. We know $X$ is an infinite set, so we can find distinct $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$ in $X$ all different from $x$.

Define $A = \{x\} \cup \{x_{2n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $ B = \{x\} \cup \{x_{2n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

What is $A \cap B$ and what do you know about $A$ and $B$?